# Mongodb: Return all except some documents where element matches

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let say this is my database:

```json
[
    {
        _id: 0,
        array: ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
    },
    {
        _id: 0,
        array: ["foo", "bar"],
    },
    {
        _id: 0,
        array: ["foo"],
    }
]
```

Now I need is :

```
{
    _id: 0,
    array: ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
},
{
    _id: 0,
    array: ["foo", "bar"],
},
```

Where we exclude foo but on only single element.

I tried with,

```
{
   "array":{
      "$not":{
         "$eq":"foo"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare it with whole array of only 1 element. (i.e. ["foo"])

```js
db.collection.find({
  array: {
    $ne: [
      "foo"
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jaORQsBmi5-)

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks. But I need to aggregate in a pipeline in python, so this return  Unrecognized pipeline stage name: 'array'